# Windows 7 re-adding Wireless Networks after removal

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I keep removing a network from windows 7 (using 'manage wireless networks') only to have the network re-appear at a higher priority level than the network I want to connect to. If I leave it on the list and move it down in priority it moves itself back up the priority list. If I uncheck connect automatically, it rechecks itself. How do I get it to go away and never come back?

EDIT: Interesting twist. Both networks are coming from the same router, but one of them is faster and more reliable than the other. I have no idea why.

Comment: Do you use another program to manage your wireless connections? for example the Dell Wireless WLAN Card Utility.

Comment: No. Windows utility only. I did a clean install of the OS to remove crapware.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Windows 7 contains a flaw that makes it extremely difficult to reconfigure or delete wireless networks.

You can only achieve this is by using `Regedit` to delete all registry references to the SSID's, **then rebooting and deleting the network from the list of `Wireless Networks`.**

Start by searching your Registry for the SSID you want to delete; here are some locations where you would usually find these entries

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\InternetSettings\Wpad
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Signatures\Managed
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Signatures\Unmanaged
```